# ReferenceError: webpack is not defined

Tags: node.js, webpack

In my webpack app I have a basic build process that's triggered by "npm run build" which executes the webpack binary and copies my index.html in /app to /dist. Whenever I run `npm run build` I get `ReferenceError: webpack is not defined` but when I run `npm start`, which starts the webpack-dev-server, everything's fine.

This is my webpack config file:

```
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var config = {
    context: __dirname + '/app',
    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/app',
        filename: 'app.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw', exclude: /node_modules/ },
            { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css!sass'), exclude: /node_modules/}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('app.css')
    ]
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') {
    config.output.path = __dirname + '/dist';
    config.plugins.push(new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin());
}

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 225):

You are missing

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
```

at the beginning of your file. If you want to optimize execution a bit, you can push it inside that `if` block of yours.

Comment: I also had to run:
`npm install --save webpack`

Comment: that should be `--save-dev` else you'll be _shipping_ webpack with production code

Comment: after writing that line, it says 'webpack is declared but never used'. How to use it?

Comment: It contains a bunch of plugins. In the example above `webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin` is used. It's best check webpack API for the exact details.

Answer (score -1):

i have the same error in my vue.Js project i remove this lines from `vue.config.js` and it solve the probleme :

```
configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        // Vue CLI is in maintenance mode, and probably won't merge my PR to fix this in their tooling
        // https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/pull/7443
        __VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS__: 'false',
      })
    ],
  },
```